# How can I make an element full height while keeping the padding?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

How can I make the `div` element below (see comment in code) full height, while keeping the padding?

I want the element to be full height while not been over the screen and keep padding of other elements.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
   <title>Survey</title>
</head>
<body class="p-5 bg-gray-50 space-y-5">
   <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-lg border space-y-3">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor at...</p>
      <div class="border"></div> <!-- This element -->
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean 'this' element, what element ?

Comment: @Ben.S the element that I commented "this element".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved with use of `flex flex-col` on a parent element and `flex-grow` on a child

```
<body class="p-5 bg-gray-50 space-y-5 min-h-screen flex flex-col">
  <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-lg border space-y-3 flex-grow flex flex-col">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor at... </p>
    <div class="border flex bg-gray-100 flex-grow"></div>
    <!-- This element -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Demo [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/8UrHTaRlAA) - try to change paddings, add more text

Answer (score 0):

Set the element to a container and set height for the element and set the padding. But make sure the height of the container should be padding+height of the element

Answer (score 0):

Please use [min-h-screen](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height#class-reference) class, and you can delete `bg-gray-100`

```
<body class="p-5 bg-gray-50 space-y-5">
  <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-lg border space-y-3">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor at...</p>
    <div class="border flex min-h-screen bg-gray-100"></div>
    <!-- This element -->
  </div>
</body>
```

***Check Tailwind Playground*** https://play.tailwindcss.com/vAWw54u3oW